# Only one of two numeric columns is displaying in ggplot2 bar chart using R

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I have a dataset with three columns. One is Player; the second is Run_Value; the third is Num_years. I want Player to appear on the Y axis, Run_Value as a bar on the X axis, and Num_Years to appear either as a smaller bar within the Run_Value bar or next to it. Below is how my bar chart is currently appearing. The Num_Years data is not displaying, which is what I need.

In addition, if at the end of each Run_Value bar its Run_Value could appear, that would be great.

I have searched Stackoverflow for a comparable question, but could not find one. If one exists, please share it link.

--I cannot see the two uploaded images on my screen and am not sure why.

**Dplyr Code**:

```
sp2358test <- spAll |>
  filter(RunValue < 0) |>
  select(Player, RunValue) |>
  add_count(Player, name="Num_years") |>
  filter(Num_years %in% c(2:8)) |>
  arrange(Num_years, Player) |>
  group_by(Player, Num_years) |>
  summarise(Run_Value = sum(RunValue))
```

**Partial dplyr results**
[image: Partial dplyr results]

**My ggplot2 code**

```
sp2358test |>
  ggplot(aes(fill=Run_Value, y=Player, x=Run_Value)) +
  geom_bar(position='dodge', stat='identity') +
  lims(x = c(-250,0)) +
  guides(fill=guide_legend(title="Legend")) +
  ggtitle("Mets Starters with Top Run Value Totals",
       subtitle = "Data from Statcast for 2008-2021") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 14, color = "black"),
        plot.subtitle = element_text(size = 11, color = "purple"),
        text=element_text(color="blue"),
        axis.text=element_text(color="black"),
        legend.title = element_text(color = "black", size = 11)
  )
```

My ggplot2 image
[image: ggplot2 image]

**Results of dput for spAll dataframe:**

```
structure(list(Player = c("deGrom, Jacob", "Dickey, R.A.", "Gee, Dillon", 
"Harvey, Matt", "Lugo, Seth", "Maine, John", "Matz, Steven", 
"Niese, Jonathon", "Pelfrey, Mike", "Santana, Johan", "Syndergaard, Noah", 
"Wheeler, Zack"), Num_years = c(8L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 5L, 3L), Run_Value = c(-240.4, -56.3, -11.2, -70.3, -8.5, 
-8.1, -16, -11.8, -20.7, -87.8, -77.5, -43.1)), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -12L), groups = structure(list(
    Player = c("deGrom, Jacob", "Dickey, R.A.", "Gee, Dillon", 
    "Harvey, Matt", "Lugo, Seth", "Maine, John", "Matz, Steven", 
    "Niese, Jonathon", "Pelfrey, Mike", "Santana, Johan", "Syndergaard, Noah", 
    "Wheeler, Zack"), .rows = structure(list(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
        5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -12L), .drop = TRUE))
```

Comment: Where should `Num_years` appear?  As a text label?  You're not referencing that column in your plot code.

Comment: @chemdork123 Each Player has a Run_Value bar. Each player also has a Num_years value. I would like each Player's Num_Year value to appear either inside his Run_Value bar as a smaller bar of a different color OR next to it as a separate bar. I am not sure how you can give it a text label. I did not know how to reference it in my plot code.

Comment: Run_Value and Num_years are different scales. Are you looking for the Run_Value to be on the bottom of the plot and the Num_years to appear at the top of the plot?

Comment: @stomper I would be interested in seeing that.

Comment: If by text label you mean putting a number at side or top of each bar showing its quantity, that can be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for. I reversed the sign of Run_Value so that the data can be plotted as positive values. I sorted the y-axis by Years. I used colors to differentiate the two x-axis. The secondary axis has to be scaled to the first so I divided by 10.  That is why it goes to 25 and the primary goes to 250.  To align, Years is scaled by multiplying by 10.

[image: visual]

```
df %>%
      mutate(Run_Value = -(Run_Value)) %>%
      ggplot() +
      geom_bar(aes(x = Run_Value, y = reorder(Player, Num_years), fill = "Run Value"), stat = 'identity') +
      geom_bar(aes(x = (Num_years * 10), y = Player, fill = "Years"), stat = 'identity', width = 0.3) +
      geom_text(aes(x = (Num_years * 10), y = Player, label = Num_years), color = "white", hjust = 1) +
      ggtitle("Mets Starters with Top Run Value Totals",
              subtitle = "Data from Statcast for 2008-2021") +
      scale_x_continuous(name = "Negative Run Value", sec.axis = sec_axis(~ ./10, name  = "Years")) +
      scale_fill_manual(name = "Legend", values = c("orange" ,"blue")) +
      theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 14, color = "black"),
            plot.subtitle = element_text(size = 11, color = "purple"),
            text=element_text(color="black"),
            axis.text=element_text(color="black"),
            legend.title = element_text(color = "black", size = 11),
            axis.title.x = element_text(color = "orange"),
            axis.title.x.top = element_text(color = "blue")) +
      labs( y = "Player (Ordered by Years)")
```

Comment: That is very creative. You have exceeded my expectations. Two questions: (1) Since in the code `legend.title` is still there, why isn't a legend displaying? (2) With regard to text labels, if they are a number placed within or at the end of each bar that shows its length, can one be put inside each blue bar just before its end? Is that easy to do?

Comment: Sorry I didn't pick up on the legend. There was no legend because I defined the fill values outside of the aes(). In order to have a legend, the fill has to be within the aes(). So I added to the aes() and used scale_fill_manual to set the fill colors. I used text_geom() with a vertical adjustment to add labels to the blue bars.  If this meets what you are looking for, don't forget to vote it up or select as the correct solution :-).  (I also changed the y-axis label from blue to black so it is not confused with the x-axis color.)

Answer (score 1):

You may want to avoid having two x-axis.  Consider the alternative of using facet_wrap.  Note you first need to put your data into a long format. I've used df for your dataset.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df2 <- df %>%
    pivot_longer(cols = c(Num_years, Run_Value), names_to = "metric")


df2 %>%
    ggplot() +
    geom_col(aes(y=Player, x = value, fill = value)) +
    facet_wrap(~rev(metric),scales = "free_x") +
    ggtitle("Mets Starters with Top Run Value Totals",
            subtitle = "Data from Statcast for 2008-2021") +
    theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 14, color = "black"),
          plot.subtitle = element_text(size = 11, color = "purple"),
          text=element_text(color="blue"),
          axis.text=element_text(color="black"),
          legend.title = element_text(color = "black", size = 11)
    )
```

It gets you to something that looks like this. The problem is that you have two variables that are using the fill scale and those two variables have very different values. What is your intention?

[image]

Comment: Good question. My intention is to enable viewers of the chart to see, for each player, the relationship between their run value and the number of years it took them to gain that run value.

Comment: I wouldn't use a fill value then because the two variables that use the fill have very different scales.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another that is closer to your original and what you describe as you want.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df2 <- df %>%
    pivot_longer(cols = c(Num_years, Run_Value), names_to = "metric")


df2 %>%
    ggplot() +
    geom_bar(aes(y=Player, x = value, group = metric, fill = metric), stat='identity',
             position = "dodge") +
    ggtitle("Mets Starters with Top Run Value Totals",
            subtitle = "Data from Statcast for 2008-2021") +
    theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 14, color = "black"),
          plot.subtitle = element_text(size = 11, color = "purple"),
          text=element_text(color="blue"),
          axis.text=element_text(color="black"),
          legend.title = element_text(color = "black", size = 11)
    )
```

You have positive numbers in one variable and negative in the other. It was important to omit the xlim otherwise it would remove all the positive values of the Num-years variable.

[image]